# Is there a better way to compare strings in python then what I have written?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, string-comparison

So I work for a company and they asked me to write some code to compare some CSV files to see if companies exist in both of them.

The issue they were having with the tools they were using is if a company for example was Apple in one CSV and Apple, Inc in another, they would be considered not a match. So I wrote a script that does the job after a lot of trial and error and a huge cut down from the original code I wrote. But I feel like there should be a package that does this for you already written.

```
import csv
import copy

newData = open("test.csv", "r")
dataBase = open("CMPList.csv", "r")

testList = list(newData)
test1List = list(dataBase)
preclin = []
cmp = []
newData.close()
dataBase.close()

notInBoth = []

for i in testList:
    new = i.strip()
    preclin.append(new)
for j in test1List:
    new = j.strip()
    cmp.append(new)

notInBoth = copy.deepcopy(preclin)

for a in preclin:
    for b in cmp:
        print(a, b)
        if a[0] == b[0]:
            if a[:4] in b[:4]:
                userinput = input("Are these the same company: [" + a + "] and [" + b + "] [y for yes, n for no]\n")
                if userinput == "y":
                    print("--------------------------------------------------------------\n")
                    print("["a + "] has been confirmed as the same company as [" + b + "]\n")
                    print("--------------------------------------------------------------\n")
                    notInBoth.remove(a)
                if userinput == "n":
                    print("----------------------------------------------------------\n")
                    print("These companies do not match. Continuing matching process.\n")
                    print("----------------------------------------------------------\n")

print("All comparisons complete, creating new CSV of companies not in our database.\n")

csvFile = open('NotInDatabase.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
for item in notInBoth:
    writer.writerow([item])
csvFile.close()

print("CSV creation complete. Exiting...")
```

Comment: This is not a trivial problem. You might find this approach relevant: https://www.enigma.com/blog/improving-entity-resolution-with-the-soft-tf-idf-algorithm

Comment: @AdrianKeister That is definitely relevant. Implementing it on the other hand is totally different monster, but thank you for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: If you solve it, let me know. I have a project in classical music I've been mulling over for a while, where I want to standardize on composer and piece names, and it's rather difficult because you get who knows what when you rip a CD.